# How to get Firebase Node Child Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

`k0instro-34 -> Competition -> -M3r2OoJBWChgg5RYkYC -> dBnfYEcY1LbrO6bRDFHvlUrPdFQ2 -> 
-M3qw5ieWPGp0S-gdrG8`

How to access `"-M3qw5ieWPGp0S-gdrG8"`?

My code is:

```
 var query = firebase.database().ref("Competition").orderByKey();
query.on("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {

        var Competition_Node = childSnapshot.key;
        console.log("<----1>" + childSnapshot.key);

        var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("Competition");
        var urlRefx = rootRef.child(childSnapshot.key);
        urlRefx.once("value", function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
                var Competition_Nodex = childSnapshot.key;
                console.log("<----2>" + childSnapshot.key);
                console.log(Competition_Node+"/"+Competition_Nodex);

                -> this not working **var queryx = firebase.database().ref("Competition").orderByChild(Competition_Node+"/"+Competition_Nodex);
                queryx.on("value", function (snapshot) {
                    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
                        //CompetitionInfo'daki Uid ile COmpetition'daki childlar
                        console.log("<----3>" + snapshot.key);**

                    });
                });

            });
        });
    });
```

I can only get it up to now **dBnfYEcY1LbrO6bRDFHvlUrPdFQ2**

Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **never** need to attach listeners to nested data. When you read a node at a location, all data from under that location is also present in the snapshot you get back. All you have to do is navigate the snapshot with `child()` (when you know the names of a child node) and `forEach()` (if you don't know the name of the child nodes), and then get the values with `val()`.

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("Competition").orderByKey();
query.on("value", function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function (l1Snapshot) {
    console.log(l1Snapshot.key); // -M3r2OoJBWChgg5RYkYC
    l1Snapshot.forEach(function(l2Snapshot) {
      console.log(l2Snapshot.key); // dBnfYEcY1LbrO6bRDFHvlUrPdFQ2
      l2Snapshot.forEach(function(l3Snapshot) {
        console.log(l3Snapshot.key); // -M3qw5ieWPGp0S-gdrG8
        console.log(l3Snapshot.val()); // true
      });
    });
  })
})
```